# Jenkins "IF and Else" not working correctly. (groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

I want to have an IF/ELSE logic  if output of env kubernetes is pekin then "do that, else "do something else".
Having problem running that script.

Comment: What kind of problem? Maybe error that tries to explain you what is wrong?.. Please edit question and provide information on problem. However I guess problem in unnecessary `$` sign inside `if ( ... )`

Comment: I want to achieve if the output of variable of "kubernetes" is pekin to a certain command and if not do something else.

Comment: `$kubernetes` is most likely a syntax error.  If you see errors or have exceptions, then please add it to the question.  I think you want `"$kubernetes"` or just `kubernetes`

Answer (score 1):

Use only **kubernetes**, please see the below code:-

```
 if ( kubernetes == "pekin"){
     echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
     } else {
```